# How to remove all Desktop Environments except GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gui, 18.04

I had Ubuntu 16 installed with GNOME.
Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 18. Now when I am logging in I can choose six different Desktop Environments:

- GNOME
- GNOME Flashback (Compiz)
- GNOME Flashback (Metacity)
- GNOME on Xorg
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu on Wayland

I want to use GNOME (which is native for Ubuntu 18) and I want to remove all unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to your computer, no one can tell you exactly which packages you should remove.  This is the general approach I would take, but there is risk of removing too much and getting stuck at a command line.

1. Find potential packages to remove.

   ```
   aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep unity
   aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep compiz
   aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep metacity
   aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep wayland
   ```
2. Remove them.

   ```
   aptitude remove [package]
   ```
3. Repeat until you cannot find any more packages to remove.
4. Install and run `deborphan` and `debfoster` to sweep up any left over packages.
5. If you remove too much and get stuck with a command line:

   ```
   nmcli device wifi   # check for internet access 
   nmcli device wifi connect "ssid" password "password"
   sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
   sudo aptitude install [whatever you think will get the GUI back]
   ```

Comment: I think this is a quite risky approach. One may quickly remove too much.

Answer (score 0):

All these "desktop environments" essentially are different flavors of gnome shell. So the installed files probably are common for more than 95%. It you really want to get rid of some of these sessions, then just remove these sessions, e.g. gnome-session to remove the gnome sessions mentioned above, or ubuntu-session to remove the Ubuntu sessions. Then you may (safely) gain some extra space by autoremove packages that were automatically installed, but are not a dependency of the other session, with the command "sudo apt autoremove". I assume you won't bother removing xorg when you use wayland, or wayland when you use xorg, otherwise you better enhance your technical skills a bit and build the system yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

When on Ubuntu, list all installed desktop Environments with:

```
a@cubo:~$  ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7625 mar 19  2018 gnome-classic.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 mag  2  2018 gnome.desktop -> gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  195 mag  2  2018 gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7001 feb 13  2018 mate.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  323 mag  2  2018 ubuntu-communitheme-snap.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  247 mag  2  2018 ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5465 set 22  2016 xfce.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5607 mar  1  2018 xubuntu.desktop
```

Having really too many of them, I will leave default "Ubuntu"  and the very quick and nice "Mate", removing uncessary with (example)

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce*
```